# Is possible to use MSAL for B2C auth login in a node Microsoft bot?

Tags: node.js, botframework, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-msal

I want to add B2C authentication to my bot.

I'm trying to use MSAL in this way:

```
var msal = new Msal.UserAgentApplication(applicationConfig.clientID, applicationConfig.authority, authCallback, {logger: logger, cacheLocation: 'sessionStorage', redirectUri: applicationConfig.webApi, postLogoutRedirectUri: 'something_to_skip_a_window_error', navigateToLoginRequestUrl: false
```

But I get an error relating with the window:

```
UserAgentReferenceError: window is not defined
    at new Storage (...\node_modules\msal\src\Storage.ts:43:42)
    at new UserAgentApplication (...\UserAgentApplication.ts:270
```

I have tried also with MSALX, but I get the same error.

Any help is welcome!

Comment: have  you tried https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-tutorial-authentication?view=azure-bot-service-3.0#to-create-an-azure-ad-v2-application? You don't need to implement the authentication feature manually.

Comment: Yes, but i need to understand a way to use B2C authentication. I have tried the example "basics-oauth" for node from the link you provided but the button not render in web-chat (appears the message 'File of type 'application/vnd.microsoft.card.oauth' instead). Also the bot emulator shows the button but gives an error when in clic on it: Parameter "url" must be a string, not undefined. Perhaps i need to make a call to B2C and get the token back in bot.on()

Comment: The test in webchat in azure uses an older version of webchat that does not support oauth cards, try it on the emulator and see what behavior you see

Comment: Hi, in the emulator i get an error when i clic the login button: Parameter "url" must be a string, not undefined.